# excel vba - assigning a spesified cell value to a variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I am facing a simple problem with my codes. I declared some values at my macro, and I want to set the value of the spesified cell ( It's a date ) to a variable. But it doesn't work and when I check it with F8, it shows that it's equal to "0".

I am open to any suggestions.

Here is the part of the code;

```
If j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Yeni Egitim" Or j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Tanitim / Reklam" Then
WA1 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 7).Value
```

As you can see, "WS_All", "Satir_bul" and "j_WS" are predefined in the macro, and I see the values of those at F8 check, but WA1 comes as "0".
I declared WA1 as Integer also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified it little bit to try the code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim WS_all As String
    Dim j_WS As String
    Dim WA1 As Variant
    Dim Satir_bul As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    WS_all = "List1"
    j_WS = "List2"
    Satir_bul = 1
    j = 1

    If j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_all).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Yeni Egitim" Or j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_all).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Tanitim / Reklam" Then
        WA1 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 7).Value
        MsgBox (WA1)
    End If
End Sub
```

and worked for me. It is possible, that you have some spaces in `Cells(8, 3)` before or/and after checked `String` and this will not fullfil condition.

Then simple `Trim` function can be used as follows:

```
If j = 1 And Trim(Worksheets(WS_all).Cells(8, 3).Value) = "Yeni Egitim" Or j = 1 And Trim(Worksheets(WS_all).Cells(8, 3).Value) = "Tanitim / Reklam" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use parentheses in your code

```
If (j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Yeni Egitim") Or (j = 1 And Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(8, 3).Value = "Tanitim / Reklam") Then
WA1 = Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(Satir_bul, 7).Value
```

Comment: I tried it with parentheses but it still gives "0". I check the values of the variables, everything works fine. It should give me the date I wrote, but still "0".